# Confusing segFault trace using PointCloudLibrary

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, point-cloud-library

Minimum reproducible error:

```
    int main( int argc, char**  argv)
{  //std::cout << "initial area_seg" << std::endl;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>() );
    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (argv[1], *cloud) == -1){   
      PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read the input file \n");
      return (-1);
    }   

  std::cout << "floor cloud" << std::endl;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud_cut; 
//custom void func that takes cloud in, and returns(by reference) cloud_cut
    area_seg(-5,5,.15,5,-5,5,cloud, cloud_cut, "null");
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr floor_cut(&cloud_cut);//Fault HERE

    return 0;
}
```

According to the trace using GBD, command reaches return 0;  but then for some reason 'step' at this point takes control back to the previous line (generally, any Cloud::Ptr declarations) which has already been deallocated. I'm not sure if this is because it's out of scope, or because smart pointer deletes them when return is reached, or if that knowledge would even help me. The segFault is a Double free error. I believe that it is being dealocated because it is out of scope and then the smart pointer is trying to clean up.
What am I missing here? Why is this happening? How can I avoid this? If you can't answer that, Is there a way to tell when an object gets deallocated(what code is run that dealocates)?
I made sure compiler optimization is off, to ensure code runs linearly.

Comment: Some problems with destructors of any of the variables used in main?

Comment: This is not a reproducible error without a definition of area_seg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that `cloud_cut` is being destructed  twice.

This line allocates `cloud_cut` on the stack and it will be destructed when the main function returns:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud_cut;
```

Similarly, when this smart pointer is destructed it will also trigger a destruction of the object to which it is pointing:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr floor_cut(&cloud_cut)
```

So instead, construct the object on the heap in the first place.